# Won't let me call an event from outside the class

Tags: .net, events, delegates

In my class I have:

```
public event WrDatabase.LoadStatus loadStatus;
```

I can call it fine inside a method in the class. But from outside when I have:

```
if (datasource.loadStatus != null)
    datasource.loadStatus.Invoke(WrDatabase.TYPE.SFORCE_COLLECTION, SObjectName);
```

I get:

- if statement: The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
- Invoke statement: I get that Invoke() is not a method on that class.

Do I need to push this into the class for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages you get are right.

An `event` is some kind of syntactic sugar around a `delegate` field in order to make sure it is used as a **broadcaster/subscriber pattern**.

From the outside of the broadcaster class, an `event` only allows subscribing and unsubscribing from it with `+=` and `-=` accessors. The `Invoke` method is not known from the outside to make sure only the broadcaster class can invoke the event. It also make sure the outside world can't clear the subscribers.

If you really want to do so, you'll need to use a `delegate` rather than an `event`. Change the type and your code should work.

As a side note. This code:

```
datasource.loadStatus(WrDatabase.TYPE.SFORCE_COLLECTION, SObjectName);
```

Actually does call the `Invoke` method:

```
datasource.loadStatus.Invoke(WrDatabase.TYPE.SFORCE_COLLECTION, SObjectName);
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was some kind of compiler restriction and your explanation makes a lot of sense.